# Split All Files In a Folder Based On Row Structure

Tags: bash, macos, unix, awk, terminal

### What I Am Trying to Accomplish

I have a folder with several hundred files, each has the same structure, Here's a sample:

```
Start Date  End Date    Code1   Code2   Vendor Identifier   Quantity    V1_1    V1_2    Currency    V1_3    ID  V1_4    V2  V3  V4  TypeID  OtherID Country_of_Sale V5  V6  V7  V8
11/27/16    12/31/16        character_value character_value 2           USD     numeric_value   character_value character_value character_value     character_value     AU              
11/27/16    12/31/16        character_value character_value 1           USD     numeric_value   character_value character_value character_value     character_value     AU              
11/27/16    12/31/16        character_value character_value 1           USD     numeric_value   character_value character_value character_value     character_value     AU                                                                                              
row count   3558                                                                                
Country_of_Sale TotalA  TotalB  TotalC  TotalD  spu TotalE  V2_1    V2_2    TotalF  V2_3    V2_4                                        
AR  0   2782223 2782223 7763.1  0.002790251 22  0.05        0.05    4626.17 5023                                        
US  0   2497603034  2497603034  2958948.67  0.001184715 111374  109.33      109.33  1763291.86  1897441                                     
DO  0   529132  529132  632.54  0.001195429 5   0.01        0.01    376.94  403                                     
EC  0   794440  794440  1669.63 0.002101644 14  0.02        0.02    994.96  1087                                        
BR  0   24397952    24397952    57932.77    0.002374493 217 0.43        0.43    34523.2 37225                                       
Ctotal  109.84                                                                              
Stotal  5680.38                                                                             
Total   5790.22
```

As you can see, each file should really be two separate files; one with header row

```
Start Date  End Date    Code1   Code2   Vendor Identifier   Quantity    V1_1    V1_2    Currency    V1_3    ID  V1_4    V2  V3  V4  TypeID  OtherID Country_of_Sale V5  V6  V7  V8
```

and one with header row

```
Country_of_Sale TotalA  TotalB  TotalC  TotalD  spu TotalE  V2_1    V2_2    TotalF  V2_3    V2_4
```

The line that separates these two always has $1 == row count (/^row count/?)

I want two outcome files, one for each header row described above. *But* there are, again, several hundred files -- all of them in a single directory --to pull those from:

### The Problem

I know my solution lies in awk. I don't know awk. I've researched for several hours, and I have figured out how to solve different parts of this, but just can't figure out how to pull it all together.

What I ultimately need is two tables that I can join (in SQL) on `Country_of_Sale`.

### Expected Result

Simple:

#### file1:

```
Start Date  End Date    UPC ISRC/ISBN   Vendor Identifier   Quantity    V1_1    V1_2    Currency    V1_3    ID  V1_4    V2  V3  V4  TypeID  OtherID Country_of_Sale V5  V6  V7  V8
    11/27/16    12/31/16        character_value character_value 2           USD     numeric_value   character_value character_value character_value     character_value     AU              
    11/27/16    12/31/16        character_value character_value 1           USD     numeric_value   character_value character_value character_value     character_value     AU              
    11/27/16    12/31/16        character_value character_value 1           USD     numeric_value   character_value character_value character_value     character_value     AU
```

#### file2

```
Country_of_Sale TotalA  TotalB  TotalC  TotalD  spu TotalE  V2_1    V2_2    TotalF  V2_3    V2_4                                        
    AR  0   2782223 2782223 7763.1  0.002790251 22  0.05        0.05    4626.17 5023                                        
    US  0   2497603034  2497603034  2958948.67  0.001184715 111374  109.33      109.33  1763291.86  1897441                                     
    DO  0   529132  529132  632.54  0.001195429 5   0.01        0.01    376.94  403                                     
    EC  0   794440  794440  1669.63 0.002101644 14  0.02        0.02    994.96  1087                                        
    BR  0   24397952    24397952    57932.77    0.002374493 217 0.43        0.43    34523.2 37225
```

### What I've Tried (By Request :))

I started with this:

```
gawk '
  /^row count/ {nextfile}
  NR == 1 {$0 = "Filename" OFS $0; print} 
  FNR > 1 {$0 =  FILENAME OFS $0; print}
' OFS='\t' dir/to/raw/files/*.txt > dir/to/munged/file/file1.txt
```

*and*

```
gawk 'FNR==1,/^Country_Of_Sale/{next} /^CTotal/ {nextfile} 
{ $0 =  FILENAME OFS $0; print }' OFS='\t' dir/to/raw/files/*.txt > dir/to/munged/file/file2.tsv
```

Which kinda works, but I want to do it in one line.

So I messed around with various permutations of this:

```
awk -F, '{print > $1}' file1
```

But to be perfectly honest, I don't really get it. I'm more comfy with already-wrangled data.

I hope I've given enough here. I certainly don't want to exploit the resource.

Comment: What have you tried? Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff. Review [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with the result (or errors) you got, and we'll help you figure it out.
Given the tags you've included, I'd expect to see bash and awk code in your question.

Comment: Thanks, @ghoti (fish??). Sorry for the malformed question. I'll get to writing up what I've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your files have the `.txt` extension and you want to name the generated files with the `.txt.1` or `.txt.2` extension, you could try something like:

```
awk 'BEGINFILE{f=FILENAME".1"} /^row count/{f=FILENAME".2";next} /^Ctotal/{nextfile} {print>f}' *.txt
```

Explanations:

1. At the beginning of the processing of each input file, variable `f` is set to `FILENAME.1` where `FILENAME` (awk buit-in variable) is the name of the currently processes file.
2. When the current line of the current input file starts with `row count`, variable `f` is set to `FILENAME.2` and the line is skipped.
3. When the current line of the current input file starts with `Ctotal` the rest of the file is skipped.
4. Variable `f` is used as the output file name for all non-skipped lines.

Comment: Thanks Renuad. Sorry for the delay getting back to you on this; I had some other stuff I needed to get to first. This solution gives me the problem I had run into before: it generates two files for each file it processes. What I would like, ideally, is just two files: one that consolidates all of the "part 1" data (with the header line from FNR==1), and one that does the same for the "part 2" data. I don't really _need_ this, but it would be a nice thing for me to have as a learning tool. Thanks again!

Comment: You should probably edit your question to explain all this. I mean, when you write *As you can see, each file should really be two separate files* it is quite difficult to imagine that you want only two output files, whatever the number of input files.